# Long last track on enhanced CD

Tags: windows-media-player

I'm trying to rip some enhanced CDs. For some of these, windows media player (11) sees the last track as a more than one hour long track. I guess it sees the included film as part of the track.

Is there a way to solve this problem with WMP? Or do I have to use other software?

Thanks, Miel.

Comment: the "enhanced" in "enhanced CD" is a data-cd-style filesystem that's usually at the end of the disc, after all the audio tracks.  it's generally ISO9660 (though could be UDF), and will show up in Windows Explorer like a regular data CD.  it's not audio data, so that's why the auto-ripper breaks.  if you can't tell WMP to only rip the other tracks, you'll need to use another tool like those suggested by skelly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this happen with CDs that include extra media, I recommend using another app to rip your CDs, like Exact Audio Copy or foobar2000, both provide secure, offset-corrected ripping, freedb database access, and encoding to the format of your choice (MP3, FLAC, Vorbis, etc), though you'll need to download the encoders separately. EAC shows you the extra media as extra, non-rippable info, and foobar2000 simply ignores the extra media when ripping.

Here are some links:
[Exact Audio Copy at the Hydrogenaudio wiki](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Exact_Audio_Copy)
[Ripping with foobar2000](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Ripping_CDs)
[CD drive offsets](http://www.accuraterip.com/driveoffsets.htm)
[LAME MP3 encoder at Rarewares](http://www.rarewares.org/mp3-lame-bundle.php)

Note that these apps are complicated at first, but they're the best tools for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The reason I use WMP is that my mp3 player only accepts WMP playlists. I guess I'll have to try combining several of these apps. Would give you +1 for the tips, but I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: you can generate playlists after the rip/encode steps.  EAC is highly recommended.